# TD elements with their own width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table like so:

```
<table class="data">
    <thead>
    <tr class="columns">
        <th>
        </th>
        <th>
            <h2>Title</h2>
        </th>
        <th>
            <h2>Location</h2>
        </th>
        <th>
            <h2>Download</h2>
        </th>
        <th>
            <h2>Analytics</h2>
        </th>
        <th>
            <h2>Uploaded</h2>
        </th>
        <th>
            <h2>Updated</h2>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
    <form>
    <tr class="row">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="1" /></td>
        <td>Some Title</td>
        <td>Some Url</td>
        <td>Some Url</td>
        <td>view Analytics</td>
        <td>Some person</td>
        <td>Some info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="2" /></td>
        <td>Some Title</td>
        <td>Some Url</td>
        <td>Some Url</td>
        <td>view Analytics</td>
        <td>Some person</td>
        <td>Some info</td>
    </tr>
    </form>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

I want to insert another `tr` containing `td`s at the bottom of the table (just after the `</form>` tag), however I do not want their width to be effected by or effect the other `td`s above them.

The table has no set widths and sizes to it's content.

How would I go about this?

Comment: you cannot just stick `form` tags in randomly in a table. Put them either in a `TD` or outside of your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another table in the last cell:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="6">
        <table>
           <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that unless you add your `<tr>`, combine all `<td>`-s into one (colspan) in it and put a nested table inside that `<td>` - in that new table you can set your `<td>`-s width

Answer (score -1):

See colspan and rowspan attributes. To be perfectly flexible you should make another table under the above table. Make the above table style="margin:0;" and the below table have something like style="margin:0;position:relative;top:-2" to make it seem like they're connected. This would be tricky to make it look the same cross browser though.